# CSS Flexbox border getting cut off at 100vh? How to make boxes full screen?

Tags: css, flexbox

I am using normalize css 3.0.3, my flexbox css is as such:

```
.container {
  display: flex; 
  border: 10px solid goldenrod;
  min-height: 100vh; /* height 100%*/
  flex-direction: row;
}

.box {
    color: white;
    font-size:100px;
    text-shadow: 4px 4px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
    padding:10px;
}

.box1 { background:#1abc9c; }
.box2 { background:#3498db; }
.box3 { background:#9b59b6; }
.box4 { background:#34495e; }
.box5 { background:#f1c40f; }
.box6 { background:#e67e22; }
.box7 { background:#e74c3c; }
.box8 { background:#bdc3c7; }
.box9 { background:#2ecc71; }
.box10 { background:#16a085; }
```

My HTML is:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="box box1">1</div>
    <div class="box box2">2</div>
    <div class="box box3">3</div>
    <div class="box box4">4</div>
    <div class="box box5">5</div>
    <div class="box box6">6</div>
    <div class="box box7">7</div>
    <div class="box box8">8</div>
    <div class="box box9">9</div>
    <div class="box box10">10</div>
</div>
```

I notice that the bottom of the border is getting cut off in google chrome, which is only visible when i "scroll down" a tiny bit. How do I get the border to fit within the window that I am looking at?

Also, if I wanted to set `flex-direction: column`, how do I get it so that each "box" fills the entire screen?

Answer (score 1):

Just set the `box-sizing` on the `.container` to `border-box` and use `flex: 1` on the flex-items.

```css
.container {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: flex; 
  border: 10px solid goldenrod;
  min-height: 100vh; /* height 100%*/
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
}

.container:nth-child(odd) {
  flex-flow: column nowrap;
}

.box {
  flex: 1;
  color: white;
  font-size:200%;
  text-shadow: 4px 4px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
  padding:10px;
}

.box1 { background:#1abc9c; }
.box2 { background:#3498db; }
.box3 { background:#9b59b6; }
.box4 { background:#34495e; }
.box5 { background:#f1c40f; }
.box6 { background:#e67e22; }
.box7 { background:#e74c3c; }
.box8 { background:#bdc3c7; }
.box9 { background:#2ecc71; }
.box10 { background:#16a085; }
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/normalize/3.0.3/normalize.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
  <div class="box box1">1</div>
  <div class="box box2">2</div>
  <div class="box box3">3</div>
  <div class="box box4">4</div>
  <div class="box box5">5</div>
  <div class="box box6">6</div>
  <div class="box box7">7</div>
  <div class="box box8">8</div>
  <div class="box box9">9</div>
  <div class="box box10">10</div>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <div class="box box1">1</div>
  <div class="box box2">2</div>
  <div class="box box3">3</div>
  <div class="box box4">4</div>
  <div class="box box5">5</div>
  <div class="box box6">6</div>
  <div class="box box7">7</div>
  <div class="box box8">8</div>
  <div class="box box9">9</div>
  <div class="box box10">10</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

> I  notice that the bottom of the border is getting cut off in google
>   chrome, which is only visible when i "scroll down" a tiny bit. How do
>   I get the border to fit within the window that I am looking at?

The `body` element comes with a [default margin](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/sample.html). It's usually 8px all around.

Override that with your own `body { margin: 0; }`.

Then, the height/width of each box is normally calculated based on the [*content box*](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_boxmodel.asp) alone. You can force the length to include *padding* and *borders*, as well, by declaring [`box-sizing: border-box`](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-ui-3/#box-sizing).

In a nutshell, the default `body` margin and `.container` borders are causing the vertical scrollbar.

Try this:

```
html {  box-sizing: border-box; }
*, *:before, *:after { box-sizing: inherit;}
body { margin: 0; }
```

[**DEMO 1**](https://jsfiddle.net/angwxtbb/)

---

> Also, if I wanted to set `flex-direction: column`, how do I get it so that each "box" fills the entire screen?

Try this:

```
.container { flex-direction: column; }
.box { flex-basis: 100vh; }
```

[**DEMO 2**](https://jsfiddle.net/angwxtbb/1/)

---

**Update** (based on comments)

The question mentions that the *normalize* CSS reset alternative is in use. This file already includes `body { margin:  0; }`. So the actual cause of the vertical scrollbar is solely the borders on `.container`. (Thanks to @DavidDomain for pointing this out.)

Comment: With *normalize.css*  there should not be any `margin` on the `body`. Or am i missing something here?

Comment: @DavidDomain, I just checked. You are correct. *normalize.css* includes `body { margin: 0; }`. I was focusing solely on the code in the question. Thank you. Answer revised.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not certain how it should appear, all I gathered is your'e having trouble with overflow? Flexbox actually doesn't count in borders in it's measurements when`box-sizing: border-box` is used. So I replaced your 10px border with an outline. Outlines never affect measurements in any situation.

I changed DEMO 2 I totally misunderstood the OP, I took a look at Michael_B's to get a clue. It came out way better than I thought. At first I was having problems with limited scrolling through 5 thru 10. Doing this fixed it:

- Made the `.container` and `.boxes` at 1000vh and 1000% respectively.
- `.container` `position: relative;` and `.box` `position: absolute;`
- Each `.box` has a `z-index` at 10 times their position. e.g. No.1 is `z-index: 10;`, No. 2 is `z-index: 20;` and so forth;

I added some defaults and resets:

```
@charset "utf-8";
/* Core CSS */
html, body { box-sizing: border-box; font: 400 16px/1.45 'Source Code Pro';  width: 100vw; height: 100vh; }
*, *:before, *:after { box-sizing: inherit; margin: 0; padding: 0; border: 0; outline: none; }
body { background: #121; color: #FEF; -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased; -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale; position: relative; }
```

For DEMO 1

Changed:

`border: 10px...` to `outline: 10px...`

For DEMO 2

Added:

`justify-content: center;` to `.container`

`flex: 1 0 auto;` to `.box`

Changed:

`flex-direction: row;` to `flex-flow: row nowrap`

**DEMO 1**

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>flexBox</title>
  <style>
    @charset "utf-8";
    /* Core CSS */
    html,
    body {
      box-sizing: border-box;
      font: 400 16px/1.45'Source Code Pro';
      width: 100vw;
      height: 100vh;
    }
    *,
    *:before,
    *:after {
      box-sizing: inherit;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      border: 0;
      outline: none;
    }
    body {
      background: #121;
      color: #FEF;
      -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
      -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
      position: relative;
    }
    .container {
      display: flex;
      outline: 10px solid goldenrod;
      min-height: 100vh;
      /* height 100%*/
      flex-direction: row;
    }
    .box {
      color: white;
      font-size: 100px;
      text-shadow: 4px 4px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
      padding: 10px;
    }
    .box1 {
      background: #1abc9c;
    }
    .box2 {
      background: #3498db;
    }
    .box3 {
      background: #9b59b6;
    }
    .box4 {
      background: #34495e;
    }
    .box5 {
      background: #f1c40f;
    }
    .box6 {
      background: #e67e22;
    }
    .box7 {
      background: #e74c3c;
    }
    .box8 {
      background: #bdc3c7;
    }
    .box9 {
      background: #2ecc71;
    }
    .box10 {
      background: #16a085;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="box box1">1</div>
    <div class="box box2">2</div>
    <div class="box box3">3</div>
    <div class="box box4">4</div>
    <div class="box box5">5</div>
    <div class="box box6">6</div>
    <div class="box box7">7</div>
    <div class="box box8">8</div>
    <div class="box box9">9</div>
    <div class="box box10">10</div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

**DEMO 2**

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>flexBox</title>
  <style>
    @charset "utf-8";
    /* Core CSS */
    html,
    body {
      box-sizing: border-box;
      font: 400 16px/1.45'Source Code Pro';
      width: 100vw;
      height: 100vh;
    }
    *,
    *:before,
    *:after {
      box-sizing: inherit;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      border: 0;
      outline: none;
    }
    body {
      background: #121;
      color: #FEF;
      -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
      -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
      position: relative;
    }
    .container {
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      bottom: 0;
      right: 0;
      left: 0;
      display: flex;
      outline: 10px solid goldenrod;
      min-height: 1000vh;
      /* height 100%*/
      flex-flow: column nowrap;
      justify-content: center;
      align-content: baseline;
      align-items: space-around;
    }
    .box {
      color: white;
      font-size: 6em;
      text-shadow: 4px 4px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
      padding: 1em;
      flex: 1 0 101vh;
      border: 10%;
      overflow: auto;
      height: 1000%;
    }
    .box1 {
      background: #1abc9c;
      z-index: 10;
    }
    .box2 {
      background: #3498db;
      z-index: 20;
    }
    .box3 {
      background: #9b59b6;
      z-index: 30;
    }
    .box4 {
      background: #34495e;
      z-index: 40;
    }
    .box5 {
      background: #f1c40f;
      z-index: 50;
    }
    .box6 {
      background: #e67e22;
      z-index: 60;
    }
    .box7 {
      background: #e74c3c;
      z-index: 70;
    }
    .box8 {
      background: #bdc3c7;
      z-index: 80;
    }
    .box9 {
      background: #2ecc71;
      z-index: 90;
    }
    .box10 {
      background: #16a085;
      z-index: 100;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="box box1">1</div>
    <div class="box box2">2</div>
    <div class="box box3">3</div>
    <div class="box box4">4</div>
    <div class="box box5">5</div>
    <div class="box box6">6</div>
    <div class="box box7">7</div>
    <div class="box box8">8</div>
    <div class="box box9">9</div>
    <div class="box box10">10</div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your root css like index.css, please remove by default css like below code.
I was also facing same issue with React project, What i did just see below one line.

```
*{
   margin:0;
 }
```